# java: abstracting methods and testing them with JUnit tests

Tags: java, junit

java beginner here:
So I have implemented a small JUnit test to understand method abstraction in java through an
interface.
However, passing values between methods and classes hasn't worked fully yet.
My test-set is a Class, an Interface and a JUnit Class

- **implementation**
  -- Codetest.java

```js
package testing;
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class Codetest {
    Myinterface inter1 = new Class1("testing... ");

    @Test
    public void testPrintme(){
        assertEquals("testing... Teststring", inter1.printme());

        inter1.changeText("now its changed... ");

        assertEquals("now its changed... Teststring", inter1.printme());
    }

}
```

-- Class1.java

```
package testing;

public class Class1 implements Myinterface {
    private String mystring;
    private String teststring;

    public Class1(String classtext){
        this.mystring = classtext;
    }
    public String printme(){
        //changeText(mystring);
        return mystring + teststring;
    }
    public void changeText(String changetext){
        teststring = "Teststring";
        this.teststring = teststring;
        this.mystring = changetext;
    }
}
```

-- Myinterface.java

```
package testing;

public interface Myinterface {
    // abstract methods
    public String printme();
    public void changeText(String changetext);

}
```

- **output**
  org.junit.ComparisonFailure:
  Expected :testing... Teststring
  Actual   :testing... null

*teststring* is never assigned a value because I havent called the method changeText in this part of the test
**What I have tried**
simply calling changeText(mystring) ( is commented ) inside printme() in class1.java  does the job but I think I could do without it ,I am looking for a solution with the constructor called from codetest. What I am not seeing here ?
Any help would be greatly appreciated !  sorry for the wrong code snippet type.

Comment: you' re right, I have now corrected it

Comment: Why do you not initialize `teststring` in the constructor? Why do you assign `"Teststring"` to `teststring` and then to `this.teststring`? Why is `"Teststring"` not a constant, considering it only ever takes one value?

Comment: `return mystring + teststring;` -> `teststring` is `null` during the first invocation. So the methods returns `testing... null`. It seems your unit tests work just fine, because you were *not* expecting that and thought it would behave differently. the unit test shows you precisely where your assumptions are wrong and where the bug in your code is.

Comment: @Polygnome thank you for your comment, I understand the test output but I cant yet get the value of teststring to pass to  'changeText'  and then to the 'printme' method , in the first invocation, without calling 'changeText' inside 'printme'

Comment: I'll repeat for @JustAnotherDeveloper initialize the testString in the constructor. And make it final. There is zero need to initialize it anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Solved thanks to the comments
By just initializing *teststring* in the Constructor

```
public Class1(String classtext){
        this.mystring = classtext;
        teststring = "Teststring";
    }
```

in Class1.java the test now works just fine

- junit output
  *Process finished with exit code 0*